# need help with haskell expression (Not in scope compiler error)

Tags: haskell, expression, ghci

Hi I have the following code

```
expression :: String →  Maybe Expr
expression s =   case parse expr s' of
      Just (a,"") →  Just a
      _           →  Nothing
    where s' = filter (λx →  x ≠ ' ') s

expr, term, factor, num, sin', cos' :: Parser Expr
num    = dbl' +++ int'

expr   = chain term '+' Add

term   = chain factor '*' Mul



func = sin' +++ cos'

var' = do
       char 'x'
       return (Var "x")

int' = do n ←  int
          return (Num (fromIntegral n))

dbl' = do n ←  int
   char '.'
   n' ←  oneOrMore number
   let c = ((show n) ⊕ "." ⊕ n')
   return (Dbl (read c))

sin' = do char 's'
   char 'i'
          char 'n'
   e ←  factor
          return (Sin e)
```

And the compiler says that the following is not in **scope** "chain", "int" "number"

Why are the compiler complaining on these commands, isn't chain, int and number well known names?

EDIT

If you where to use the following parser, how would you solve the problem?

```
module Parsing
 ( Parser,parse,
  success,failure,sat,pmap,char,digit,
  (+++),(<:>),(>*>),(>->),(<-<),
  oneOrMore,zeroOrMore
 )

where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Char

------------------



-------------------
-- Basic Parsers, dependent on internal structure --
-- success and fail
failure    = P $ \s -> Nothing
success a  = P $ \s -> Just (a,s)

-- Parse any single character
item  =  P $ \s -> case s of
               []     -> Nothing
               (c:cs) -> Just (c,cs)

-- (+++)  parse either using p or else using q
infixr 5 +++
(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a

p +++ q  = P $ \s -> listToMaybe [ x | Just x <- [parse p s, parse q s]]

-- (p >*> f) parse using p to produce a.
-- Then parse using f a

infixl 1 >*>

(>*>) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b

p >*> f  = P $ \s ->
            case parse p s of
                    Just(a,s') -> parse (f a) s'
                    _          -> Nothing

-----------------------------------------------


-- pmap modifies the result of a parser
pmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
pmap f p = p >*> success . f

p >-> q = p >*> \_ -> q  -- equivalent to monadic op: >>
p <-< q = p >*> \a -> q >-> success a


(<:>):: Parser a -> Parser [a] -> Parser [a]
p <:> q = p >*> \a -> pmap (a:) q
```

Comment: It looks like your indentation is broken in the end. Also, is this Parsec code?

Answer (score 1):

(What version of parsec are you using?)

There's no `chain`, `int`, or `number` provided by Parsec 2.x or Parsec 3.x, though these would be simple to write.

```
chain term op cons = sepBy1 expr (char op) >>= return . foldr1 cons
int = many1 digit >>= return . read
number = digit
```

(Untested, and I'm just guessing at the intent of your code.)

---

Cute little parser combinator library there.  Is this homework or something?

```
punva grez bc pbaf = cznc (sbyqe1 pbaf) $ grez <:> mrebBeZber (pune bc >-> grez)
vag = cznc ernq $ barBeZber qvtvg
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using some sort of parsing library like Parsec, or the [parser module](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/Parsing.lhs) from "programming in Haskell." You need to import the one you are using.